# VB.NET - Check if the key pressed is the same as the text in label

Tags: vb.net, keypress

I am wondering if anyone can help me to do the above question.

Basically what i have is a label which has had a randomly generated letter placed into it.

What I want to do is to show a msgbox (just to show that it works for now) when the same key in the label is pressed. I have tried two methods but none seem to work, could anyone point me in the right direction? It doesn't seem like it would be that hard, i am just new to coding.

```
Private Sub speedtyping_Keydown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress

    If (e.KeyChar = lblletter1.Text.ToString) Then
        MsgBox("WORKS")
    ElseIf (e.KeyChar = lblletter2.Text) Then
        MsgBox("words")
    End If
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Could their be a chance that the "Private Sub speedtyping...." onwards is incorrect? I really don't know what i could be doing wrong.

Comment: If you want to handle the KeyPress event for the form (rather than just a control), you need to set the form's `KeyPreview` property. You can do that in the Form Designer, or you can add `Me.KeyPreview = True` to the form's Load event handler. If you do that, your code should work.

Comment: Yes thank you very much blackwood! not sure how i can thank you though, :(

Comment: Note: Switch Option Strict On to catch errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to handle the form's `KeyPress` event, you need to set it's `KeyPreview` property. You can do that in the Form Designer or in the form's `Load` event handler as below.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.KeyPreview = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = lblletter1.Text(0) Then
            MessageBox.Show("WORKS")
        ElseIf e.KeyChar = lblletter2.Text(0) Then
            MessageBox.Show("words")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub speedtyping_Keydown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress

If (e.KeyChar.ToString = lblletter1.Text) Then
    MsgBox("WORKS")
ElseIf (e.KeyChar.ToString = lblletter2.Text) Then
    MsgBox("words")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Well it works for me, so you are doing something wrong. Make sure your labels have the correct text. Also this IS case sensitive, so check this too.

Comment: Yea its not working for me :L, not sure how you are getting it to work using yours because it definitely doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub speedtyping_Keydown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress

If (e.KeyChar.Trim() = lblletter1.Text.Trim()) Then
    MsgBox("WORKS")
ElseIf (e.KeyChar.Trim() = lblletter2.Text.Trim()) Then
    MsgBox("words")
End If

End Sub
```